# How do I use MaterialFilePicker?

Tags: java, android, filechooser

I am trying to use [MaterialFilePicker](https://github.com/nbsp-team/MaterialFilePicker) for my Android Java music player.  I have included it in my two `build.gradle` files, and have adjusted my `colors.xml` and `styles.xml` files accordingly, but can't figure out where to go next.  The `readme.md` file in the GitHub repository told me this:

> Open your class and add the following code

And provided me with this code:

```
...
public static final int FILE_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE = 989
...

MaterialFilePicker()
    // Pass a source of context. Can be:
    //    .withActivity(Activity activity)
    //    .withFragment(Fragment fragment)
    //    .withSupportFragment(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment fragment)
    .withActivity(this)
    // With cross icon on the right side of toolbar for closing picker straight away
    .withCloseMenu(true)
    // Entry point path (user will start from it)
    .withPath(alarmsFolder.absolutePath)
    // Root path (user won't be able to come higher than it)
    .withRootPath(externalStorage.absolutePath)
    // Showing hidden files
    .withHiddenFiles(true)
    // Want to choose only jpg images
    .withFilter(Pattern.compile(".*\\.(jpg|jpeg)$"))
    // Don't apply filter to directories names
    .withFilterDirectories(false)
    .withTitle("Sample title")
    .withRequestCode(FILE_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE)
    .start()
...
```

But I can't figure out how do implement this code.
I have created a file called `MaterialFilePicker.java` and have modified the code provided to look like this:

```
package com.infinityfreeapp.formalsoftware.audioplayer;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import MaterialFilePicker;

public class MaterialFilePicker {
    public static final int FILE_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE = 989;


    MaterialFilePicker() {
        // Pass a source of context. Can be:
        //    .withActivity(Activity activity)
        //    .withFragment(Fragment fragment)
        //    .withSupportFragment(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment fragment)
        .withActivity(this)
        // With cross icon on the right side of toolbar for closing picker straight away
        .withCloseMenu(true)
        // Entry point path (user will start from it)
        .withPath(alarmsFolder.absolutePath)
        // Root path (user won't be able to come higher than it)
        .withRootPath(externalStorage.absolutePath)
        // Showing hidden files
        .withHiddenFiles(true)
        // Want to choose only jpg images
        .withFilter(Pattern.compile(".*\\.(jpg|jpeg)$"))
        // Don't apply filter to directories names
        .withFilterDirectories(false)
        .withTitle("Sample title")
        .withRequestCode(FILE_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE)
        .start();
    }
}
```

But it is still riddled with errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material File Picker seems outdated and not very well documented.

I would recommend [storage chooser](https://github.com/codekidX/storage-chooser) which seems much more documented and professional.

For example, to implement it, put this in your dependencies:

```
com.github.codekidX:storage-chooser:2.0.4.4
```

And then you can use it to pick files like this:

```
// Initialize Builder
StorageChooser chooser = new StorageChooser.Builder()
.withActivity(MainActivity.this)
.withFragmentManager(getFragmentManager())
.withMemoryBar(true)
.allowCustomPath(true)
.setType(StorageChooser.FILE_PICKER)
.build();

// Show dialog whenever you want by
chooser.show();

// get path that the user has chosen
chooser.setOnSelectListener(new StorageChooser.OnSelectListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSelect(String path) {
        Log.e("SELECTED_PATH", path);
    }
});
```